Issues with Delta Sharing API when using Service Principal Token
I am currently working with the Delta Sharing API and have encountered an issue when using a Service Principal token for authentication. The API call returns the following error:
[CANNOT_INFER_EMPTY_SCHEMA] Can not infer schema from empty dataset.
However, when I use a personal access token, the API works as expected.
My questions are:

Does the Delta Sharing API only support personal access tokens for authentication?
Is there any additional configuration or permission required when using a Service Principal token for Delta Sharing?
Has anyone else encountered this schema inference error, and how can it be resolved?

Thanks

Add more details on how you are using service principal for authentication.

Hi Jayashankar,We start by creating an Azure AD (AAD) token using the Service Principal credentials (client_id, client_secret, and tenant_id). This AAD token is used for authenticating API requests.

Hi Jayashankar,

Created an Azure AD (AAD) token using the Service Principal credentials . This AAD token is used for authenticating API requests.
using that AAD token I created a databricks PAT token valid for 3 months. The AAD token is passed in the Authorization header to authenticate the request to Databricks.
Once I have PAT, I used it in python code
python
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {secret_token}"}
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
Let me know if you need any further details


did you follow this to generate token https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/auth/oauth-m2m.html#manually-generate-a-workspace-level-access-token

Yes, I follow exactly the same steps.

You first add your service principal in databricks settings like below.

Next, click on Add new.

Then select Microsoft Entra ID managed  and give client id.

After adding now create a secret.

Using this secret generate new databricks PAT token for authorization.

Getting the same error with the secrets: [CANNOT_INFER_EMPTY_SCHEMA] Can not infer schema from empty dataset.

Can you check the permissions once. Does your service principle have enough permission on schema and table.

we have "all privilages" permissions for SP on catalog, schema and table.

Can you add your code which is used to read this table.

Due to charter limitation splitting the code in 2 comments
import requests
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_unixtime, from_utc_timestamp
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("LoadSharesData").getOrCreate()
tk = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="dev",key="kydev")
api_url = "https://x.x.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.1/unity-catalog/shares"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(tk)}
#headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer xx"}
response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

shares = data.get("shares", [])
df = spark.createDataFrame(shares)
df = df.withColumn("created_at", from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(col("created_at") / 1000), "PST"))
df = df.withColumn("updated_at", from_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(col("updated_at") / 1000), "PST"))
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable("ctg.sch.tb")
